# Observe window resize event with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsview, nswindow, nsnotifications

I currently have a `LazyVGrid` setup as such:

```
struct NetworkGrid: View {
    var networks: [Network]
    let columns = [
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible()),
            GridItem(.flexible())
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(networks) { network in
                    NetworkCard(network: network)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to set the number of grid columns based on the current window size, i.e.

```
func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
    itemWidth = CGFloat(300)
    if window.width <= itemWidth {
        GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())
    } else if window.width <= itemWidth * 2 {
        GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())
    } else if window.width <= itemWidth * 3 {
        GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())
    }
    ...
}
```

How would I go about implementing such an observer with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SwiftUI equivalent of listening for window size would probably be using a `GeometryReader`. In your example, you can read the size and dynamically decide the columns based on its width reading:

```
struct NetworkGrid: View {
    var networks: [Network]
    
    func columnsForWidth(width: CGFloat) -> [GridItem] {
        print("Columns for width: \(width)")
        return Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: Int(width) / 100)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columnsForWidth(width: geometry.size.width)) {
                    ForEach(networks) { network in
                        NetworkCard(network: network)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works awesome! It doesn't seem to appear when I embed it in another view and trigger with a button switch. Any ideas?

Comment: The console will print `Columns for width: 1356.0` `Columns for width: 0.0` `Columns for width: 1356.0` upon calling the view.

Comment: It may be that it doesn't appear when embedded in a list.

Comment: You'd have to show me an example -- not quite sure what scenario exactly you're talking about.

Comment: I will also say (in advance) that `GeometryReader` doesn't measure the size of the full window -- it only measures the size of it's own view. So, to get the whole size of the window, it has to be the highest-level view.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to update `@State` or `@ObservedObject` variables when the view is resized, you can use [onAppear(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/AnyView/onAppear(perform:)) to update the variables with the initial view size and [onChange(of:perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/onChange(of:perform:)) to detect view size changes:

```
struct MyView: View {
  @State private var size: CGSize = .zero

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ZStack {
        Text("Hello World")
      }.onAppear {
        size = geometry.size
      }.onChange(of: geometry.size) { newSize in
        size = newSize
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve this without GeometryReader:

```swift
let networkCardSize = 200

ScrollView(.vertical) {
    LazyVGrid(
        columns: [
            // Move an item across rows iff it has enough space
            // to contain *just* the item (+ padding).
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: networkCardSize, maximum: networkCardSize)
        ],
        alignment: .leading,
        spacing: 0
    ) {
        ForEach(networks) { network in
            NetworkCard(network: network)
                .padding(10)
        }
    }
}
```

`spacing` didn't work as expected for me, but probably has a good solution. I'm also not sure how dynamically sized elements fare here. Static sizes are great tho!

[image: gif with items in grid that move to other rows when window size can't show entire row]